# Should I exchange usleep by sleep_for

Tags: c++, c++11

I am in the stage of upgrading some legacy C++ code to C++11 under Linux using gcc. When trying to set priorities I came up with the following question. Could there be any advantage in exchanging a call to `usleep` with a call to `std::this_thread::sleep_for`? In the code I am talking about the running thread is supposed to wait for a very short period. Therefore I don't need any advanced features like interrupting the sleep.

Comment: Yes, it will improve code portability.

Comment: Every time you change code you run the risk of introducing a bug so, if it 'aint broke don't fix it. However if you are fixing the function anyways why not move to more portable, standard code?

Answer (score 13):

Yes. [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) is specified by the C++11 standard, and is therefore a portable solution on any system with a C++11 compiler and standard library.

`usleep` is specified by POSIX.1-2001 (and declared obsolete!), which means it can only be (reliably) used on POSIX compliant systems.

POSIX.1-2008 removes the specification of `usleep`, in favour of `nanosleep`. For this reason alone, `std::this_thread::sleep_for` is a much better choice.

(See http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep for details).

Comment: I understand that I should prefer std-conforming functions over POSIX functions. But should I expect any side effects? Could sleep_for behave differently than usleep? Could there be a performance benefit or penalty?

Comment: Not as far as I can see. Both are specified to sleep for _at least_ the duration specified (i.e. it may be longer, depending on scheduling, etc.)

Comment: As for performance concerns, the only sensible course of action is to _profile_ the two solutions. I can't imagine there'd be a significant difference between the two; not compared to the wait time, anyway.